# std::vector указателей долго освобождает память

Tags: c++, многопоточность, память

Я считываю много данных из файла и заполняю ими вектор (про резервирование вектора знаю). После некоторых манипуляций с данными, я освобождаю память.

```
std::vector<unsigned int*> values;

//Резервирую память вектора, заполняю его данными с выделением памяти под них
//Обработка данных

for ( auto &value : values ) {
    delete value;
}
```

Вроде задача тривиальна, однако напоролся на следующую проблему - у меня выходит около 32 миллионов элементов, и, понятное дело, их обработка занимает длительное время, однако, когда я дохожу до освобождения памяти, скорость освобождения начинает падать тем сильнее, чем больше памяти я уже освободил. Таким образом, память освобождается более получаса.

Я подозреваю, что виной всему range-based for, но, видимо, не до конца понимаю как он работает и как быть с этой проблемой.

Пробовал разбить вектор на два и память из одной половины освобождать в другом потоке. Это значительно снизило время освобождения большинства памяти, но всё равно занимало слишком много и, в конце концов, не решило проблему. Грубый пример кода:

```
const std::size_t halfSize = values.size() / 2;
std::vector<unsigned int*> splitLow(values.begin(), values.begin() + halfSize);
std::vector<unsigned int*> splitHigh(values.begin() + halfSize, values.end());

auto lambdaMemoryRelease = []( auto &values ) {
    for ( auto value : values ) {
        delete value;
    }
};

std::thread thread( lambdaMemoryRelease, std::ref( splitLow ) );
lambdaMemoryRelease( splitHigh );
thread.join();
```

Затем решил пойти дальше и добавить ещё парочку потоков, и по ходу дела возникло ещё несколько вопросов (в комментариях):

```
const auto numberOfThreads = 3;

auto lambdaMemoryRelease = []( auto &values ) {
    for ( auto value : values ) {
        delete value;
    }
};

const auto pieceSize = values.size() / (numberOfThreads + 1);
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for ( auto i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; ++i ) {

    std::vector<unsigned int*> splitValues( values.begin() + (i * pieceSize)
        , values.begin() + ((i + 1) * pieceSize));//Не совсем уверен, как это будет 
            //работать - что будет создан вектор, содержащий указанный диапазон 
            //итераторов понятно, но после выхода из блока for он должен быть очищен, 
            //и что произойдёт с ссылкой на вектор, переданной в лямбду?

    std::thread thread( lambdaMemoryRelease, std::ref( splitValues ) );
    threads.push_back( thread );
}

lambdaMemoryRelease( std::vector<unsigned int*>(values.begin() + (pieceSize * numberOfThreads)
    , values.end() ) );

for ( auto &thread : threads ) {
    thread.join();//Расчёт на то, что если какой-либо из потоков ещё 
        //не завершит работу, мы остановимся и дождёмся его, и так с
        //каждым потоком, а если поток ранее завершил работу, то не 
        //остановимся вовсе
}
```

В результате код вышел странненьким и не особо рабочим.

Итого, как быть с медленным освобождением памяти при большом количестве элементов, и какие ответы на вопросы в комментариях к последнему коду?

Comment: Тут много раз упоминается слово "медленно", но нигде нет никаких замеров или цифр. Как нет и воспроизводимого примера такого поведения. Хранение в векторе указателя на unsigned int выглядит втройне подозрительно, так как если указатель на один элемент - то он не имеет смысл, если на несколько - то в программе неопределенное поведение из-за неправильного удаления, ну и вообще непонятно, зачем что-то удалять вручную. В С++ указатели нужны по большей части для взаимодействия с С. Последний кусок кода вообще ни разу не рабочий, непонятно, зачем еще плодить векторы?

Comment: Выделять память для новых векторов для освобождения памяти - это как выделять водку на борьбу с алкоголизмом.

Comment: @VTT как таковых замеров я не делал, лишь периодически проверял в дебаге, память из под какого элемента сейчас освобождается, и если из под первых миллионов она освобождалась за десятки секунд, впоследствии время на освобождение каждого элемента росло. Полагаю дело в цикле, допускаю, что после освобождения памяти из под элемента, проход начинался с начала, что странно... Касательно указателей, мне нужно было отсортировать вектор, для чего я использовал std::sort, а он ругался и дребовал указатели, вот вы и дал ему то, чего он хотел

Comment: @VTT Вы про вектора с диапазоном из итераторов (не уверен как правильно называется)? Ничего адекватнее в голову не пришло, вот и сделал так

Comment: "проверял в дебаге" - измерение производительности в дебаге не особо толковое занятие. "std::sort, а он ругался и дребовал указатели" - да у вас тут еще и проблема XY...

Comment: @VTT согласен, стоило проверить в релизе, прежде чем паниковать. Проверю вечером. Можно подробнее про XY?

Comment: [проблема XY](https://7bloggers.ru/xy-problem/), проблема X - это использование sort, а Y - вектор с указателями, которое было бы не нужно, если бы разобрались с sort

Comment: Гм... На что указывает элемент вектора? Если вы просто создаете `new unsigned int` и помещаете указатель в вектор - что-то не понимаю, зачем. По-моему, проще помещать сами значения. Если ну категорически нужен именно вот такой вариант - то опять же, как мне кажется, пользовательский аллокатор, который освобождал бы память одним куском, решил бы проблему...

Comment: @Harry элемент вектора просто число, считанное из файла, по большому счёту, не значащее ничего. Указатель использую по причине ошибочной интерпретации результата `std::sort`, почему то предположил, что не указатели он не обрабатывает, уже поправил. Правильно ли я понимаю, что пользовательский аллокатор - это, по сути, простой самописный интеллектуальный указатель?

Comment: @VTT Вы правы, оказалось достаточным разобраться с `std::sort`, изначально неверно интерпретировал результат сортировки и начал творить бред. Спасибо.

Comment: Нет, имеется в виду выделение памяти под элементы вектора (второй параметр шаблона), а в вашем случае - еще и свой оператор new для выделения памяти под числа. Например, выделяющий память блоками по миллиону чисел, и просто возвращающий очередной элемент, а при освобождении - освобождающий всю память сразу, а не каждые 4 байта по отдельности. Подробнее надо писать большой ответ, а не комментарий, конечно...

Comment: @Harry думаю суть уловил, попробую изучить этот вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( auto i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; ++i ) {

    std::vector<unsigned int*> splitValues( values.begin() + (i * pieceSize)
        , values.begin() + ((i + 1) * pieceSize));

    std::thread thread( lambdaMemoryRelease, std::ref( splitValues ) );
    threads.push_back( thread );
}
```

Здесь `splitValues` - объект в стеке, с каждой итерацией будет вызван конструктор и деструктор. А вы отдаёте адрес в рабочем стеке нитям. Всё должно полностью обрушится. Сначала создавайте вектор в куче так:

```
std::vector<unsigned int*> * psplitValues = 
  new std::vector<unsigned int*>(values.begin() + (i * pieceSize)
    , values.begin() + ((i + 1) * pieceSize))
```

и удаляйте потом. *Желательно, чтобы это сделали сами нити.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в целом я так и предполагал, но хотелось разобраться. Хотел бы уточнить, "Желательно, чтобы это сделали сами нити." - как именно? Вы имеете ввиду такую запись `std::thread thread( lambdaMemoryRelease, std::ref( new std::vector<unsigned int*>(values.begin() + (i * pieceSize), values.begin() + ((i + 1) * pieceSize))) );` , или передачу всего контейнера в нить, с последующим получением нужного диапазона итераторов? Как будет корректнее?

Comment: Если вектор, как аргумент для нити больше никому не нужен после заканчивания её работы, то проще пусть сама нить занимается удалением данного аргумента. Для главного потока эта задача будет тяжелее в три раза.

Answer (score -6):

Вообще-то std::vector нужен только если заранее неизвестен размер вектора и надо вектор пополнять в рантайме заранее неизвестным числом элементов. Если размер вектора заранее известен, то лучше пользоваться std::array. Если же время становится критично, то можно написать свой массив с полным контролем всех операций.

UPD1:

И вообще, если уж затрагивать философские основы, то программирование с использованием stl превращает С++ в Яву. Контроль над распределением памяти утрачивается, все переменные перекочевывают в кучу с соответствующим оверхедом по времени в виде запроса-освобождения памяти. Итераторы тоже все живут в куче. Вобщем получается нормальная такая Ява. Ну и за что боролись? Проще работать на Яве и не париться.

UPD2:

> Все равно его в куче хранить придется.

Зато его освобождать быстро так как это один кусок памяти. А std::vector это же не вектор на самом деле, а список со всеми вытекающими последствиями в виде долгого времени доступа и долгого времени освобождения всех цепочек.

> А как же кастомные аллокаторы?

Ну и чем помогут кастомные аллокаторы? Свою кучу писать и в ней выделять место? Так тоже самое и будет что в общей куче, быстрее не будет.

> "Итераторы тоже все живут в куче" Почему это?

Ну понятно что это от реализации зависит, но в общем случае закон не писан могут и в куче расположить если данных в итераторе много надо хранить и их размер заранее неизвестен.

UPD3:

> Список - в смысле связный список?

Ну конечно. std::vector это эмуляция массива с помощью списка. Внутри у std::vector содержится список из векторов. Запрашиваются маленькие вектора по 100-1000 элементов и в них добавляются элементы. Когда все места становятся заняты, то запрашивается еще один маленький вектор, который помещается в список. И так далее. А иначе никак не возможно сделать вектор с переменным размером.

UPD4:

> vector - это непрерывный участок.

Как известно, при создании std::vector не указывается его размер. Поэтому std::vector не может быть непрерывным участком, так как при добавлении элементов неизвестно, сколько надо резервировать места.

UPD5:

> std::vector представляет собой неразрывный в памяти массив элементов

Увы, но это не так. Именно поэтому у Вас так долго удаляется std::vector (конечно если у Вас нет еще и других ошибок). Ну конечно полчаса на удаление даже 32 миллионов беззнаковых целых это слишком, даже в дебажной версии. Скорее всего у Вас там и какие-то другие ошибки.

> а переменный размер контейнера достигается путём аллокации нового
>   участка памяти, с последующим копированием данных в неё и
>   освобождением памяти в прошлом куске памяти

Если бы это было так, то любое добавление в вектор занимало бы (в общем случае) время О(n) (где n текущий размер вектора) что явно неприемлемо ни по каким законам, ни Божеским, ни человеческим.

> std::vector представляет собой неразрывный в памяти массив элементов

Вот std::array он да, представляет собой неразрывный в памяти массив элементов. Ну зато std::array не умеет изменять свой размер. А std::vector никак не может представлять неразрывный в памяти массив элементов по всем вышеизложенным причинам.

Вообще-то чем спорить, лучше надо поглядеть реализацию std::vector где-нибудь в приличном месте, ну хотя бы в VS. Когда-то давно я глядел реализации stl. Но это было дело муторное, там и тогда сам черт ногу сломал бы. А сейчас особенно.

UPD6:

> размер увеличивают в N (1.5 или 2) раза

Не, ну сделать можно как угодно криво. Ну вот у человека 32 мега интов в векторе. Ему надо добавить 1 элемент, а ему сразу отводят еще 32 мега пустой памяти? И это называется полный контроль над памятью и экономное использование ресурсов? А если у него вектор на гигабайт? Что, сразу второй гигабайт ему отвалят? Это не наш метод и с таким подходом система завалится на раз-два-три.

> The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be
>   accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular
>   pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a
>   vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an
>   element of an array.

Действительно, такое написано. Правда там приписка есть что все это - (since C++03). Вобщем если это действительно сделано так начиная с 2003 года, то значит что начиная с 2003 года std::vector нельзя применять для сколько-нибудь больших векторов. То есть если на 10 килобайт данных еще потянет, то большие массивы данных будут либо постоянно занимать время на перекопирование, либо отхватывать по слишком большому куску памяти и дополнительно в этот момент перекопирования гига данных вся программа будет тормозиться что тоже не далеко фонтан.

UPD7:

> Вместо этого размер увеличивают в N (1.5 или 2) раза, когда место в
>   векторе кончается. За счет этого получается вставка за
>   (амортизированное) О(1).

В std::vector есть метод insert (начиная с С++11). Если хранить данные в std::vector в виде неразрывного массива в памяти, то insert будет выполняться за О(n). И никакие увеличения размера в 1.5 или 2 раза тут не помогут получить "амортизированное" О(1). И что же, прикажете при каждом insert перекопировать весь вектор?

Скорее всего непрерывный участок памяти получается при выполнении метода data. Это как было сделано в std::string. Хранятся данные по кусочкам, но есть метод c_str, которые заводит непрерывный буфер и копирует в него данные.

Comment: Учитывая "миллионы элементов", упомянутые в комментах, не уверен, чем `std::array` здесь лучше `std::vector`. Все равно его в куче хранить придется. Проблема ТС в том, как я понимаю, что он под каждый отдельный инт выделяет отдельный кусок памяти в куче. *"Контроль над распределением памяти утрачивается"* А как же кастомные аллокаторы? *"Итераторы тоже все живут в куче"* Почему это?

Comment: *"`std::vector` это же не вектор на самом деле, а список со всеми вытекающими последствиями"* Не понимаю. Список - в смысле связный список? Вектор же в одном куске памяти хранит все элементы, не хуже выделенного в куче `std::array`.

Comment: "Внутри у std::vector содержится список из векторов" - вы явно что-то путаете. Примерно такой структурой обладает deque, а не vector. vector - это непрерывный участок.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, std::vector представляет собой неразрывный в памяти массив элементов, а переменный размер контейнера достигается путём аллокации нового участка памяти, с последующим копированием данных в неё и освобождением памяти в прошлом куске памяти, потому, если количество элементов заранее известно, стоит использовать std::vector.reserve(), чтобы не заниматься реаллоцированием памяти много раз.

Comment: *"UPD5: Увы, но это не так."* [RTFM](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) же, ну. *"The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array."* - "Элементы хранятся [в памяти] подряд"

Comment: Дальше: *"Если бы это было так, то любое добавление в вектор занимало бы (в общем случае) время О(n)"* Насколько я помню, это было бы так, если бы каждый раз добавлялось место ровно под один элемент. Вместо этого размер увеличивают в N (1.5 или 2) раза, когда место в векторе кончается. За счет этого получается вставка за (амортизированное) О(1). Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550509/amortized-analysis-of-stdvector-insertion

Comment: *"Итераторы тоже все живут в куче"*, "*std::vector это эмуляция массива с помощью списка*" - закусывать надо

Comment: Ой, как все запущено... :(

Comment: Мда, столько бреда в одном месте...